# Running gulp tasks with laravel elixir doesnt version all js files

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I have this gulpfile.js
https://gist.github.com/kristapsveveris/c25ba60984d8f3602d68

When I run gulp task, the result is :
[image]
<sub>(source: [maxtraffic.com](http://maxtraffic.com/assets/img/public-assets.png))</sub>

rev-manifest.json contains :

```
{
  "assets/js/all.js": "assets/js/all-d764f790.js",
  "assets/css/all.css": "assets/css/all-189848ae.css",
  "assets/css/serve-desktop.css": "assets/css/serve-desktop-037f21da.css",
  "assets/css/serve-mobile.css": "assets/css/serve-mobile-b0a650b6.css"
}
```

So the problem is that versioning doesn't create 'campaign.js' and 'serve.js' only their .map files

And if I run :

```
 gulp --production && gulp version --production
```

All versioning file are created

I'm running gulp tasks from windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of laravel-elixir are you using? This was a [bug with elixir < v0.14.2](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7353)

It looks like when concatenating a lot of files (or more likely, the output file is large), then it did not get versioned with the rest of the files.

It looks like you can run `gulp version` separately and they will get versioned. If you are experiencing this issue then `gulp` or `gulp watch` will not do it.

Here is my gulp file, **vendor.js** was being compiled but not versioned. It is not even the last file being versioned:

```js
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {

    mix.sass('app.scss')

    .scripts([
        'react/react-with-addons.min.js',
        'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js'
    ], 'public/js/vendor.js', 'resources/assets/bower')

    .scripts(['app.js'], 'public/js/app.js', 'resources/assets/js')

    .version([
        'css/app.css',
        'js/vendor.js',
        'js/app.js'
    ]);

});
```

Running `gulp version` afterwards will version it.

It was fixed for me with laravel-elixir v0.14.2

Comment: Updated laravel-elixir from 0.14.0 to 0.18.7 and it fixed versioning problem. 
Now elixir throws this notification when compiling "File not found: ./vendor/bower_components/bootsrapvalidator/dist/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js" but in reality file is included, so it isn't a problem. Thank you.

Comment: Had problems with 0.18.* version so moved to 0.14.2 as you suggested  and now everything works as expected